# Adding data in CoreData takes a lot of time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a model in *CoreData* looks like this:
[image]

The structure of the adding looks like tree, for example:

```
let context = CoreDataManager.instance.getContext()
for i in stride(from: 0, to: (RegionNames.count)!, by: 1){    
    let regions = Regions(context: context)
    regions.name = RegionName
    for j in stride(from: 0, to: (DistrictNames.count)!, by: 1){
        let districts = Districts(context: context)
        districts.name = DistName
        regions.addToRegToDist(districts)
        for k in stride(from: 0, to: (StreetNames.count)!, by: 1){
            let streets = Streets(context: context)
            streets.name = StreetName
            districts.addToDistToStr(streeets)
            for k in stride(from: 0, to: (AddressNames.count)!, by: 1){
                let addresses = Addresses(context: context)
                addresses.name = AddressName
                //+few attributes
                streets.addToStrToAddresses(addresses)
                districts.addToDistToAddresses(addresses)
                regions.addToRegToAddresses(addresses)
            }
        }
    }
}
CoreDataManager.instance.saveContext(context: context)
```

Regions class and others entities looks like this:

```
public class Regions: NSManagedObject {
    convenience init(context:NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Regions", in: context)

        self.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    }
}
```

Is's work completely but adding take a long time. I have only static Activity Indicator in the UI. Nothing changes. I feel something is not right but i don't know how to change it.

**Edit:**

I used this setup for example:

```
RegionNames.count == 1
DistrictNames.count == 10
StreetNames.count ~ 10-15 //in each district
AddressNames.count ~ 500 //items in each district or about 10-50 items in each streets.
```

I have the same app on Android and saving takes a max of 15 seconds. However, this app works about 8 minutes which is absolutely unacceptable.

CoreDataManager class with getting and saving context (iOS > 10.0):

```
    class CoreDataManager {

    // Singleton
    static let instance = CoreDataManager()

    private init() {}

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Addresses")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext?

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        } 
    }

    func saveContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext){
        if (context.hasChanges){
            do {
                try context.save()
                //print("saved!")
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            } catch {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is **long time** in your opinion and why do you call it long time , what are you comparing it too when you do? How many items are you inserting, and what long time is the result of the items you insert? Provide more details if you want someone to be able to help you. For now its only guesswork.

Comment: Depending on how big `RegionNames.count`, `DistrictNames.count`, etc, are, you are potentially inserting an **enormous** number of objects here. How many times do you expect each loop to run?

Comment: Are you using a contexts that is attached to the main thread?

Comment: I removed relationships addressToDist and addressToReg and inverse. This resulted in winning 2 minutes but it's not enough.